# Phantom Padding/Margin/Space at the bottom on my page

Tags: html, css, web

I have had some issues with phantom space that keeps popping up randomly and annoyingly at the bottom of my pages for a site Ive been working on with another developer. Ive looked in dragonfly dozens of times and i cannot find anything with extra padding or margins holding it down there. negative (-) margins don't bring it back up etc EXTREMELY annoying and i eel the answer is likely simple.

Our ide preview of this is here: http://razzly-shauwe.codio.io:3000/Contact.php (doesnt always work. a vm has to be turned on for this to function)

but a jsfiddle with irreverent code stripped out is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/webnetvn/eeqo3f7L/

```
it says i need code for a jsfiddle link?
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<div class="first">` has a padding top of 15px which is pushing the box down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should **delete** the `padding-top:15px` from `.first` class and **add** it to `.footspecial` to align your `.first` element properly.